# Is it an assumption or truth for spatial and temporal variables separation if Hamiltonian is time-independent in Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

For the derivation from time-dependent Schrodinger equation to time-independent Schrodinger equation, if the Hamiltonian is time-independent, we assume the spatial and temporal variables in the wave-function are separable.

$$\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)T(t)$$

Is this an assumption or truth? If it's an assumption, what is the assumption in details?

Comment: Neither nor. It is a general technique to solve PDE's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations

Comment: thanks. Is there an entanglement between spatial and temporal function if the Hamiltonian is time-indepdent?